# Windows management via Tomcat application

Tags: windows, tomcat, application

Is there something like [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) that runs on tomcat and is easy to deploy for Windows operating system?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all of the Windows management tools are in GUI form to begin with, so I've never seen a web-based control panel for Windows.

If you're trying to admin the box remotely/across the web, why not configure RDP to run on a non-standard port and use that?

Comment: I would argue that RDP on a non-standard port isn't precisely "security through obscurity" - it's just good practice if you're exposing it to the outside world.  Ideally you'd use VPN and then RDP, but the web-based aspect of your question made me think you're looking for something that could be published.  In terms of management features... which ones?  If disk space/CPU and the like are what you're looking for, why not look into Nagios or an SNMP system?

Comment: RDP by default allows 2 concurrent users to access it.  If you really think you'll have more than 2 users checking the server at any one time, then it is a non-starter.  That being said, I've found in my organization that we don't run up against that much so long as users understand they must log off the session and not just close it.  Aside from that, no, there isn't that I'm aware of.  Windows admins tend to just use RDP so that product hasn't had much need.  If you are concerned about monitoring, set up Nagios to let you when things go wrong/go above a certain threshold, then use RDP.

Comment: Nagios is just an example.  You can pick your monitoring solution of choice - Nagios, Zabbix, simple SNMP, a commercial agent like Zenith or Kaseya - I just think your best bet is going to be monitoring joined to RDP for management.  Or you could go with LogMeIn or something that shares the console session - though none of those will allow for an infinite number of users able to logon concurrently.